# resolve stale element within loop python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a python script to loop throws rows and perform an action on each row - a simple double click and authorize. It works perfectly for the first row, but then when it gets to the second row, it throws a "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

Now, I understand that the issue is that the web page refreshes after I perform an action on the first row, and therefor the 2nd row is no longer active even though it's there.

I just don't know how to get around this. If someone can provide some input I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#capture the rows
tables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[starts- 
with(@id,'revalgridview') and contains(@class,'x-grid-item')]")

#loop through each row
for row in tables: 

        time.sleep(5)

        # check user who made the changes
        authorizations = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[1].text

        if authorizations == "TCCCOPS_DC" or authorizations == "TCCCOPS_RC": 
              actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
              actionChains.double_click(row).perform()
              time.sleep(3)

              #click authorize button 
              auth = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Authorize')]")
              auth.click()
              time.sleep(5)

       else:
              continue
```

[Reval Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21EgI.png)

Comment: http://allselenium.info/handle-stale-element-reference-exception-python-selenium/

Comment: it looks like the data set changed while you were sleeping on the executing thread.

Comment: You use wrong locator for the rows, please share HTML in text format. Does page redirect to another after Authorize click?